# Shower tile layout suggestions

Tags: bathroom, ceramic-tile

I am tiling my shower surround and I have a platform that is approximately 1’x3’ that I need to tile as well.  I am looking for layout suggestions on what area I should tile first and if the horizontal surface of the platform should overhang enough to be flush with the vertical surface?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t you be using “green board” in a shower? https://www.diytileguy.com/bad-ways-to-build-a-tile-shower/

Comment: I’m using water resistant hardibacker with a ‘wet area’ thinset and grout. The rest of the room is green board

Comment: what kind, size of tile? and what do you mean "should overhang enough to be flush with the vertical surface" ?

Comment: 2x4 inch subway tile. I was just wondering how to handle the lower vertical to horizontal corner.  Basically should the edge of the horizontal tiles lay flush with the face of the vertical surface to create a grout line or the other way around? I have added another pic to illustrate my question better (I hope)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with your 2nd option. Columns E and F in the spread sheet. and i would use a bull nose edged tile. **I. E.** *a tile that is designed to have the edge exposed*. Other wise you will see the unfinished edge.

This is more aesthetically pleasing and will not put a grout line at the edge that would collect water and not let it flow over the edge of the tile.